# Spark : how can i create local dataframe in each executor

Tags: scala, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

In spark scala is there a way to create **local dataframe in executors like pandas in pyspark**. In mappartitions method i want to convert iterator to local dataframe (like pandas dataframe  in  python) so that dataframe features can be used instead of hand coding them on  iterators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible.

[Dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes) is a distributed collection in Spark. And Dataframes can only be created on driver node (i.e. outside of transformations/actions).

Additionally, in Spark you cannot execute operations on RDDs/Dataframes/Datasets inside other operations:
e.g. following code will produce errors.

```
rdd.map(v => rdd1.filter(e => e == v))
```

DF and DS also have RDDs underneath, so same behavior there.